# ffmpeg piping to aucdtect in a batch file

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-file, pipe

I am trying to pipe ffmpeg output to auCDtect in a batch file like this:

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -acodec pcm_s16le -f wav - ^| auCDtect.exe --
```

For some reason aucdtect just freeze at

```
Data analysis:          [0%]
```

My ffmpeg version is 3.0.1 and i am sure it can decode the input file correctly.

Comment: Doesn't look [good](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,48016.0.html).

Comment: i see, it's an aucdtect bug. The only workaround is to use a temporary file instead of piping.